# Rails deploy: 4 small servers or 1 big server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, horizontal-scaling

I have $20/m to spend.

DigitalOcean 512MB-1CPU droplet cost $5/m each. A 2GB-2CPUs droplet cost $20/m.

I'm wondering if I should go with:

- 1 front proxy + 2 app servers + 1 DB server 512MB each
- 1 server with 2GB + 2CPUs?

Which will output better performance?

Comment: How many RPS (requests per second) are you going to handle at beginning? How many users will visit your site per day?

Comment: I'm not sure, as the our website is a new Question/Answer site for locals. We're targeting to have at least 30,000 hits/month after a month or two. I would try to go with 4 servers plan to easier scale up (like adding another app server), but I'm not sure if 512MB is something too weak?

Comment: In my experience, one Rails instance will happily take 400MB RAM or more, so with a 512MB host you are pushing that box to the limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

30,000 hits/month = 1000 hits/day = 0.7 hits/min - in this case you can purchase **one** $5 VPS for beginning and install application (2 Rails workers) and DB to it.

2 rails workers will take about 100-200 MB per worker (400-500MB for big project, but this is not your case). DB will take about 50-100MB. Typical workload will be less 10%, so 1 CPU will works fine.

In case if you will have more hits just use vertical scalability (i.e. upgrade your one instance).

So, for beginning your choose is one $5 or $10 VPS.

P.S.
  I am hosting similar project on one $5 VPS in configuration described above. Typical RPM (requests per min) is about 70-120. All works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are the 4 small servers hosted by the same hosting company? in which case they allocate the memory and CPU usage from one or more of their server computers. In which case I would bargain that both options would give you the exact same performance.

I would however in my opinion choose the single server because of the easier accessibility.

Comment: They're hosted by the same hosting company. I'm wondering if using 1 server makes it's harder to scale in the future? Like when I just want to add one more app server to the cluster? And if 512MB is too weak, or not optimum, like as in a 2GB, you could make use of all the remain RAM.